# xml to matching rows with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I need help with transforming my xml to a html table with two columns with matching rows. My xml-tei file structure for the columns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<teiHeader></teiHeader>
<text>
<body>
<div type="poem">
<head n="1"><hi rend="underline">Sjudubaeots'oh</hi></head>
<div type="column1">
<lg>
<l n="1">Jaanguoi<add place="above">goj</add> ninje</l>
<l n="2"><add place="top">Njaar pie<del rend="overstrike">v</del><add 
place="above">b</add>es</add></l> 
<l n="3">Njaar jan|deata</l>
<l n="4">Opoj habidoo</l>
<l n="5">Tab<add place="above">b</add>adooda habih</l>
<l n="6">Njaar jan|deata</l>
</lg>
</div>
<div type="column2">
<lg>
<l n="1" xml:lang="ru">На земили хребты</l>
<l n="2"><add place="top">три братев</add></l>
<l n="3" xml:lang="ru">Три на<note resp="#MAC" place="top" xml:lang="swe">på jorden ej så rika</note> землы оленщик<note resp="#MAC" 
place="above">Deatáh, оленщикъ</note> (богатые)</l>
<l n="4" xml:lang="ru">одинъ работник у ихъ</l>
<l n="5" xml:lang="sw">På <del rend="overstrike">песачиый</del><add 
place="above">худий</add> слуга <note resp="#MAC">(namn) d.ä hans pimi  äro vardsrlösa, utan band, hänga ned (<hi rend="underline">tabbaltaa</hi>) 
</note></l>
<l n="6" xml:lang="sw">Af de tre bröder</l>
</lg>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</text>
</TEI>
```

I need a table with two columns, which would have lines matching each other. The place of the line inside lg is determining (rather than the n of the line).

This is what I tried, based on the code proposed. It produced only one column with text in column 1 following the text in column 2. I do apologize my previous question, which showed the initial xml too simple, and probably produced the confusion. Obviously, I am quite ignorant in xslt, but all the more hope you could help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="3.0">
<xsl:output method="html" html-version="4.0"/>
<xsl:template match="TEI/text/body/div[div[starts-with(@type, 'column')]]">
<table>
<thead><xsl:value-of select="head[@n='1']"/>
</thead>
<xsl:variable name="row-count" select="count(div[1]/lg/l)"/>
<xsl:for-each-group select="div/lg/l" group-by="position() mod $row-count">
<tr>
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="l">
<td>{ . }</td>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Does the `n` attribute value determine that two `l` elements belong into the same `tr` row? Or the position inside the `lg` element? In any way, it looks like it could be solved with grouping and in any case tell us which XSLT version you use or can use because many things are easier in XSLT 2 or 3 than in XSLT 1.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
It seems the your second suggestion, positional grouping, suites better, as it is the position inside the lg element that determines the matching of the lines.
For me, though, both your solutions produce a one column division, where the text in the div column 1 is followed by the text in the div column 2. I would like to see them side by side in two different columns.

Comment: The sample I linked to shows the table output with two columns, I think as you describe it, I have also now edited the answer so that you can see the result directly on StackOverflow.  I can't tell what you have tried or changed, you will need to edit your question and show the details or ask a new one with the necessary details (minimal but complete sample of XML, XSLT, result you want and the one you get) to explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can group the `l` elements on the `n` attribute:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[div[starts-with(@type, 'column')]]">
      <table>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="div/lg/l" group-by="@n">
              <tr>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </tr>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="l">
      <td>{ . }</td>
  </xsl:template>
```

Full XSLT 3 example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtN.

As an alternative you can use positional grouping:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[div[starts-with(@type, 'column')]]">
      <table>
          <xsl:variable name="row-count" select="count(div[1]/lg/l)"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="div/lg/l" group-by="position() mod $row-count">
              <tr>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </tr>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="l">
      <td>{ . }</td>
  </xsl:template>
```

XSLT 3 sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtN/2, the HTML table markup produced there is

```
  <table>
     <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>lmn</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>efg</td>
        <td>opq</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>hij</td>
        <td>rst</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

which looks like

```
abc lmn
efg opq
hij rst
4   4
```

Comment: Thank you for this.